# DAO: How to use the return value from Insert

Tags: android, database, kotlin, android-room, dao

According to [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data) an `@Insert` function can return a `long`, which is the new `rowId` for the inserted item. How can I use the return value?

```
@Dao
interface TodoDao {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
        fun insert(todo: TodoItem): Long
}
```

Just to note the `id` for my `@Entity` is autogenerated.

```
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
```

Here is the whole `TodoItem` entity.

```
@Entity(tableName = "todos")
@Parcelize
data class TodoItem(val text: String, val priority: Priority) : Parcelable {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var todoId: Long = 0
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `id on`TodoItem`is a`var`, you could assign the return value to`id`, so now your entity has its generated primary key, for use with future DAO operations.

---

If you are going to use `@Parcelize`, ensure that all essential properties are in the `data class` constructor. As it stands, your `todoId` property would not get put into the `Parcel`.

```
@Entity(tableName = "todos")
@Parcelize
data class TodoItem(
    val text: String,
    val priority: Priority,
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) var todoId: Long = 0
) : Parcelable
```

Then, given an entity named `entity` and a DAO named `dao`:

```
entity.todoId = dao.insert(entity)
```

Comment: Would you be so kind to provide me with the code? I am still not sure how to do that.

Comment: @Slazer: It's just an assignment. However, your edited question pointed out another problem.